# How to handle google login for a widget

Tags: javascript, authentication, widget, social-authentication

I'm in the process of creating a widget. The part that escapes me is implementing social media authentication.

The widget is done through embedded javascript, and takes over a `<div>` on the page rather than utilizing an iframe.

The problem that I am having is that I would like to avoid redirects. Not because I don't want to handle them, but because I want to make the widget as friendly as possible. The basic google signin button creates a popup which handles the authentication client side. It is absolutely perfect for my use case, except that it requires a client_id:

```
<script>
window.googleStart = function() {
  gapi.load('auth2', function() {
    auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
      client_id: '639034356632-fgcp4bigtn908q2ev3qifl9vfqnsciuj.apps.googleusercontent.com',
      // Scopes to request in addition to 'profile' and 'email'
      //scope: 'additional_scope'
    });
  });
}
</script>
```

I might be wrong, but I believe that if I use this method while being embedded onto someone's website I could overwrite their client_id and cause conflicts, or perhaps google would just void the second init attempt and use their client_id. In either case I don't believe that's what I should be doing. Is there any way to setup client side authentication without redirection so that my widget does not interfere with the google api that the website may be using?

I have a method that uses redirection and avoids this problem, but I would really like to be able to complete the entire social authentication without moving from the page the widget is embedded on.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a new window target to the gAuth.

Comment: I can't believe it didn't even occur to me. Using the server side authentication it opens google authentication in a new page where I can login. After logging in, it requires a redirection. How would you go about updating the original page to reflect the successful login? Would using sockets be the best way, just redirect the login to a page that automatically closes and tells the server to send the widget the login information?

Comment: Sorry but i don't use the gAuth at all... I hope that someone will can answer you, have a nice night, ~TBD